# Error in creating jar file though application running properly in Eclipse

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to build AI path finding application in Java. It is working properly in Eclipse with no error but i am getting compilation warning when creating a jar file and thus it is no running. The error is from following class sourcode. Please help me! Thank you

[image]

```
package aStar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections; 
import  aStar.util.ClosestHeuristic;

/**
 * The class which uses AStar based algorithm to determine the path. 
 * @author Dorji Gyaltsen
 */
public class AStarPathFinder{

    /** The set of nodes which have been searched(ClosedNode) 
     * and yet to be searched(OpenNode) */
    private ArrayList closedNode = new ArrayList();
    private OpenList openNode = new OpenList();

    /** The instance of the map being searched */
    private Map map;

    /** The maximum searchDepth of search */
    private int maxSearchDistance;

    /** The total set of nodes in the map */
    private Node[][] nodes;

    /** allowance of diagonal movement */
    private boolean DiagonalMovement;

    /** The heuristic to determine which node to search first */
    private AStarHeuristic heuristic;

    /**
     * Constructor initialising all the variables
     */
    public AStarPathFinder(Map newMap, int newMaxSearchDistance, 
                           boolean newDiagonalMovement, ClosestHeuristic newheuristic) {
        map = newMap;
        maxSearchDistance = newMaxSearchDistance;
        DiagonalMovement = newDiagonalMovement;
        heuristic = newheuristic;

        /**Node definition and initialisation **/
        nodes = new Node[map.getWidth()][map.getHeight()];
        for (int x=0;x<nodes.length;x++) 
            for (int y=0;y<nodes.length;y++) 
                nodes[x][y] = new Node(x,y);
        }

    /**
     * The main method which find the path based on AStar algorithm **/
    public Path searchShortestPath(UnitMover mover, int sx, int sy, int dx, int dy) {

        //if the path is blocked
        if (map.pathBlocked(mover, dx, dy)){ 
            return null;
        }else {

        //if the path is not blocked
        nodes[sx][sy].pathCost = 0;
        nodes[sx][sy].searchDepth = 0;
        closedNode.clear();
        openNode.clear();
        openNode.add(nodes[sx][sy]);

        nodes[dx][dy].parent = null;

        // When the destination is not reached
        int maxSearchDepth = 0;
        while ((maxSearchDepth < maxSearchDistance) && (openNode.size() != 0)) {
            Node current = getFirstOfOpenNode();
            /**if current node is the destination node then stop**/
            if (current == nodes[dx][dy]) {
                break;
            }
            else {

                clearFromOpenNode(current);
                addToClosedNode(current);

                // search all curentNode neighbours considering as the next closest node
                for (int x=-1;x<2;x++) {
                    for (int y=-1;y<2;y++) {

                        // if it is the current node
                        if ((x == 0) && (y == 0)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if (!DiagonalMovement){
                            if ((x != 0) && (y != 0)) 
                                continue;
                        }
                        else {
                            // determine the location of the neighbour and evaluate it
                            int xn = x + current.x;
                            int yn = y + current.y;

                            if (isValidLocation(mover,sx,sy,xn,yn)) {
                                float nextNodePathCost = current.pathCost + map.getPathCost(mover, current.x, current.y, xn, yn);
                                Node neighbour = nodes[xn][yn];
                                map.pathFinderVisited(xn, yn);

                                // if the new pathCost we've determined for this node is lower than 
                                // it has been previously makes sure the node hasn't been discarded.
                                if (nextNodePathCost < neighbour.pathCost) {
                                    if (inopenNode(neighbour)) 
                                        clearFromOpenNode(neighbour);
                                    else if (inclosedNode(neighbour)) 
                                        clearFromclosedNode(neighbour);

                                }

                                // if the node hasn't already been processed and discarded then
                                // reset it's pathCost to our current pathCost and add it as a next possible
                                if (!inopenNode(neighbour) && !(inclosedNode(neighbour))) {
                                    neighbour.pathCost = nextNodePathCost;
                                    neighbour.heuristic = heuristic.getPathCost(map, mover, xn, yn, dx, dy);
                                    maxSearchDepth = Math.max(maxSearchDepth, neighbour.setParentNode(current));
                                    addToopenNode(neighbour);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // since we've got an empty openNode openList or we've run out of search 
        // there was no path. Just return null
        if (nodes[dx][dy].parent == null) 
            return null;


        // At this point we've definitely found a path so we can uses the parent
        // references of the nodes to find out way from the destination location back
        // to the start recording the nodes on the way.
        Path path = new Path();
        Node destination = nodes[dx][dy];
            while (destination != nodes[sx][sy]) {
            path.prependStep(destination.x, destination.y);
            destination = destination.parent;
        }
        path.prependStep(sx,sy);

        // thats it, we have our path 
        return path;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the first element from the openNode openList. This is the next
     * one to be searched.
     * 
     * @return The first element in the openNode openList
     */
    protected Node getFirstOfOpenNode() {
        return (Node) openNode.first();
    }

    /**
     * Add a node to the openNode openList
     * 
     * @param node The node to be added to the openNode openList
     */
    protected void addToopenNode(Node node) {
        openNode.add(node);
    }

    /**
     * Check if a node is in the openNode openList
     * 
     * @param node The node to check for
     * @return True if the node given is in the openNode openList
     */
    protected boolean inopenNode(Node node) {
        return openNode.contains(node);
    }

    /**
     * clear a node from the openNode openList
     * 
     * @param node The node to clear from the openNode openList
     */
    protected void clearFromOpenNode(Node node) {
        openNode.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Add a node to the closedNode openList
     * 
     * @param node The node to add to the closedNode openList
     */
    protected void addToClosedNode(Node node) {
        closedNode.add(node);
    }

    /**
     * Check if the node supplied is in the closedNode openList
     * 
     * @param node The node to search for
     * @return True if the node specified is in the closedNode openList
     */
    protected boolean inclosedNode(Node node) {
        return closedNode.contains(node);
    }

    /**
     * clear a node from the closedNode openList
     * 
     * @param node The node to clear from the closedNode openList
     */
    protected void clearFromclosedNode(Node node) {
        closedNode.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Check if a given location is valid for the supplied mover
     * 
     * @param mover The mover that would hold a given location
     * @param sx The starting x coordinate
     * @param sy The starting y coordinate
     * @param x The x coordinate of the location to check
     * @param y The y coordinate of the location to check
     * @return True if the location is valid for the given mover
     */
    protected boolean isValidLocation(UnitMover mover, int sx, int sy, int x, int y) {
        if((x < 0) || (y < 0) || (x >= map.getWidth()) || (y >= map.getHeight())){
            return false;
        }
        else{

        if ((sx != x) || (sy != y))
            if(!map.pathBlocked(mover, x, y));
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A simple sorted openList
     * @author Dorji Gyaltsen
     */
    private class OpenList {
        /** The openList of elements */
        private ArrayList openList = new ArrayList();

        /**
         * @return The first element from the openList
         */
        public Object first() {
            return openList.get(0);
        }

        /**
         * Empty the openList
         */
        public void clear() {
            openList.clear();
        }

        /**
         * Adding an element to open ist and sorting
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void add(Object o) {
            openList.add(o);
            Collections.sort(openList);
        }

        /** 
         * @return The total number of element in the openList
         */
        public int size() {
            return openList.size();
        }

        /**
         * @return True if the element is in the openList
         */
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            return openList.contains(o);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A single node in the search graph
     */
    private class Node implements Comparable {
        /** The x and y coordinates of the node */
        private int x;
        private int y;

        /** The path pathCost for this node */
        private float pathCost;
        /** The parent of this node*/
        private Node parent;
        /** The heuristic pathCost of this node */
        private float heuristic;
        /** The search searchDepth of this node */
        private int searchDepth;

        /**
         * The creation of a new node
         * @param x and y The x and y coordinates of the node
         */
        public Node(int x1, int y1) {
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
        }

        /**
         * Set the parent for this node 
         * @param parent The parent node which lead to this node
         * @return The searchDepth for searching
         */
        public int setParentNode(Node parent) {
            searchDepth = parent.searchDepth + 1;
            this.parent = parent;

            return searchDepth;
        }

        /**
         * compareTo(Object)
         */
        public int compareTo(Object other) {
            Node o = (Node) other;

            float f = heuristic + pathCost;
            float of = o.heuristic + o.pathCost;

            if (f < of) return -1;
            else if (f > of) return 1;
            else  return 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of error you're getting?

Comment: Delete all this irrelevant code from your question and replace it with the actual error you are getting.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik my compiler didn't any detail about the error but it says some errors in this file

Comment: So would you like us to take some stabs in the dark about your problem?

Comment: Nope, but i wondering how to change the compiler setting to figure out the problem. I am so sorry being so naive.

Comment: How are you trying to build your `Jar` file? For the record, as @MarkoTopolnik mentions, your question is vague. You list your whole code, without any errors pasted. It's really hard for us to debug your problem with part of the information not posted along your question. If your compiler gives an error, it has to be something specific, and that's what we need.

Comment: Well, thank you for your response. The above image is one i got after creating jar file.

Comment: While i checked in my eclipse source code for this file, it says Arraylist is a raw type. References to generic type Arraylist<E> should be parameterized. what that supposed to mean?

Comment: The warning you is not the reason your program is not running. The JAR has been created but the code had some warnings. If your code is not running, show what exactly is not running or not doing what you would expect.

Comment: I saw the above yellow triangle near the arraylist code otherwise there is no problem of running it in eclipse

Comment: Now i fixed that yellow errors and there is no warning while creating jar file. But it is not running. When i run form cmd line by typing java -jar Project.jar i am getting "The image is not available. Cant read input file"

Comment: Please guys! now it says "no main manifest attribute in project.jar file"

Comment: How did you build your jar file?

Comment: Package/Export/Java/JAR file/ and next and next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem most probably comes from the fact that your jar file is incomplete. As per your comment, it seems you have exported only part of your project into a jar file. You should try the [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) Eclipse extension to generate your jar file. The website contains all the documentation you need.

Additionally, the class you have shown contains no `main` method. You will need one somewhere in your project in order to run your application using only your jar file.

Comment: Thank you for you kind response. Well, i have main method in other main class. I will look at the link you have given. Now the problem i am struck is with the "The image is not available and cant read input"

Comment: Here is image reading code i have in main class : image[Map.GRASS] = ImageIO.read(new File("res/grass.png")); please comment

Comment: @Dorji This new problem happens because the reference to the file doesn't work when you are using your jar file. You should Google how to use image resources when inside a jar file, you will most probably find the answer to your problem. SO probably has a few questions on the matter. If no question corresponds to your actual problem, you should ask another question, as this one is related to the jar creation (we don't like having more than a question in a question).

Comment: Thank you for you kind response. I will do the response on that topic. I really appreciate your time and effort. Good day